# Pretty Permlinks on NGINX for Wordpress - CentOS 7

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, centos7

I am trying to activate pretty permalinks on my wordpress installation, but no success. I'm changing this file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

I tried the following:

```
server{   
 if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
```

---

```
server {
if ($host ~* ^myhost\.com$) {
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.myhost.com$1 permanent;
    break;
}
```

---

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
```

---

But none of these worked :(. Here is my full file:

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;

}


    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;

     note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
           index  index.php index.html index.htm;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;      

    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;  
      }
    }
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`

Comment: Also: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

Comment: Have you read the WordPress documentation on using nginx?https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Comment: Arcesilas, tried this too but no success. Moshe Katz, Yes I read it but I don't know why there is something wrong with my file :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  your-domain.com www.your-domain.com;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/your-wp-root-dir;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to restart your `nginx` server after updating `default.conf` file ( `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart` )

Comment: Sark, thanks for your help. But this is not working :(

This is driving me insane. I don't know what to do. I know it looks like I'm doing something wrong, but I'm following every single step and this thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late,

try

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;
}
```